# Disassembly and Shipping of bike

Tags: road-bike, transportation

I have a road bike lying around in a garage in California. I would like to use it here in Illinois. However, there's no one out there who can disassemble and pack the bike for me in California, ALTHOUGH there's someone to open the garage :-).

Is there a service that disassembles, packs and ships the bike for me? Or at least disassemble and pack the bike so that I could use a pickup service myself?

Comment: See also: http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/5/how-to-get-a-bike-from-one-city-to-another-in-the-u-s

Answer (score 9):

Some bike shops will disassemble and pack a bike for shipping. For a fee, of course.

Comment: I have found it's often cheaper to use a bike shop than do it yourself - they have commercial arrangements with carriers that offset the cost of paying them to do pack the bike. The cost should be no more than 1 hour (more likely 1/2 hour) labor. They should/usually provide a bike box for free (think of all the new bikes they sell - where do they put the empty boxes). factor in the time and hassle - get a bike shop to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Consider shipping by train.

Oops, heard wrong -- checked with my son who just did this:

Remove pedals, turn/remove bar, use box you purchase from them or you can sometimes get a used one for free.